# API to Google sheets - unable to fetch data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to fetch data via API to Google sheets, I am able to get "NewConfirmed" and other few fields but not able to get "Countries" data. Please help.

```js
function Covid19() {
  
  // Call the COVID19 API
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.covid19api.com/summary");
  
  // Parse the JSON reply
  var json=response.getContentText();
  var data=JSON.parse(json);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var i = 2;

  for each (var info in data)
    {
      sheet.getRange(i,1).setValue([info['NewConfirmed']]);
      sheet.getRange(i,2).setValue([info['Country']]);
     
      i = i + 1;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If you log data, you will see

> {Countries=[{CountryCode=AX, TotalRecovered=0.0, NewDeaths=0.0,
>   Slug=ala-aland-islands, Country=ALA Aland Islands, NewRecovered=0.0,
>   Date=2020-04-21T12:32:01Z, NewConfirmed=0.0, ...

Thus, in order to retrieve `Country` and `NewConfirmed` you need to define

`var data=JSON.parse(json).Countries` and then you have to iterate through all entries within a loop.

Sample based on your code:

```
function Covid19() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.covid19api.com/summary");
  var json=response.getContentText();
  var data=JSON.parse(json).Countries;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
      sheet.getRange(i+2,1).setValue([data[i]['NewConfirmed']]);
      sheet.getRange(i+2,2).setValue([data[i]['Country']]);
  }
}
```

> Sidenote:
>
> It is ot good practive to use `getRange(...).setValue(..)` during each
>   loop iteration. It would be better to write the data into an array and
>   assign the array with all the data to the sheet after finishing
>   iteration.

Comment: Thanks a tone, that's just perfect